# how to define regex to parse just TLD of domain name?

Tags: regex

I have something as:-

```
....wasasa.org.pk
wawwwsasa.msn.com

....ttrt .....ddd.dd www.edu.pk
.ru
```

I only want to pick following

```
org.pk
.com
edu.pk
```

The possible regex i wrote is

> [a-z]+.(.*)(?=\s+)

The problem is that its only picking on dd part.

With the latest regex i see following problems:-

> ....wasasa.org.pk fgf wawwwsasa.msn.com fgf
>
> ....ttrt .....ddd.dd www.iffn.pk fgf
>
> www.ru ff www.ru.com fgfgf
>
> .ru fgf

It will stop matching anything after space e.g www.ru.com fgfgs. The regex should work with space and even without space.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Maybe try something like this?

```
((?:edu|org)?\.[a-z]+)$
```

Comment: @asadz Yes, (?: ... ) is a non-capture group. It... will not be captured into a group ^^;

Comment: There is a slight problem if I add ....wasasa.org.pk fgf which is space after .pk it will start to match fgf for me i don't want the match to stop well before that.

Comment: @asadz I made a bracketing mistake, oops! Try to see if the updated regex works ^^;

Comment: kindly see my updated question.

Comment: @asadz But how should the regex distinguish between `.dd` and `.pk`? At most you can do something like [this](http://www.regex101.com/r/zK7aN0).

Answer (score 0):

If I did understand the question awk can do it using:

```
awk '{split($0,uri,"/");c=split(uri[3],domain,".");
domain[1]=="www"?a=3:a=2; for (i=a;i<=c;i+=1){
printf("%s%s"),domain[i],i==c?"\n":"."}}'
```

A sample usage:

```
printf "%s\n" 'https://google.com/search?q=google' 'https://www.google.co.uk/foo' | awk '{split($0,uri,"/");c=split(uri[3],domain,"."); domain[1]=="www"?a=3:a=2; for (i=a;i<=c;i+=1){ printf("%s%s"),domain[i],i==c?"\n":"."}}'
```

Output:

```
com
co.uk
```